# What does $?VAR mean in csh?

Tags: shell, macros, csh

I've encountered this code written in csh:

```
if ( ! $?LM_LICENSE_FILE ) then
    setenv LM_LICENSE_FILE $_LmLicense
else
    switch("$LM_LICENSE_FILE")
    case *${_LmLicense}*:
         breaksw
    default:
         setenv LM_LICENSE_FILE "${_LmLicense}:$LM_LICENSE_FILE"
    endsw
endif
```

Please note this line:

```
if ( ! $?LM_LICENSE_FILE ) then
```

What does `$?` do in `$?LM_LICENSE_FILE`?

`LM_LICENSE_FILE` is a shell variable (or macro, more precisely), and I know that `$LM_LICENSE_FILE` is used to retrieve its value, but a trailing question mark following `$`, that is `$?LM_LICENSE_FILE`, what is its meaning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$?VAR` expands to 1 (true) if `$VAR` is set (to anything, even the empty string), 0 (false) if it isn't.

This is documented in the [csh manual](http://www.unix.com/man-page/OpenSolaris/1/csh/); follow the link and search for `$?`, or type `man csh` or `man tcsh`.

Oh, and csh doesn't have macros.

Answer (score 1):

`if ( ! $?LM_LICENSE_FILE ) then` 
means `if ( LM_LICENSE_FILE has not been assigned with any value.) , then` ...

On the other hand, `if ( $?LM_LICENSE_FILE ) then` 
means `if ( LM_LICENSE_FILE has been defined or assigned.) then`