# Behaviour of 'ECHO' in csh and bash

Tags: bash, shell, csh

I was writing few scripts and suddenly stroke me to think the following commands in CSH and BASH shells.

**In csh shell**

```
$ echo $?BASH
  0
$ echo $?HOME
  1
$ echo $? home
  0 home
```

**In bash shell**

```
$ echo $?BASH
  0BASH
$ echo $?HOME
  0HOME
$ echo $? home
  0 home
```

Someone explain the above behaviour. I know the **echo $?** prints the exit status of the last command but if added with some string then how its working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975968/what-does-var-mean-in-csh. I also didn't know so i searched it and found that in about 20 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you review the documentation csh indicates:

```
$?name 
${?name} 
Substitutes the string 1 if the variable name is set, 0 if it is not.

$?0 
Substitutes 1 if the current input file name is known, 0 if it is not.
```

http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/csh.1.asp

be careful, $? is diferent to $?name

Comment: Thanks! And what about in BASH?

Comment: Since `?BASH` is not a valid parameter name, the `bash` parser knows that `$?BASH` consists of two parts: the parameter expansion `$?` and the literal string `BASH`.