# $? tcsh script issue

Tags: variables, if-statement, undefined, csh, tcsh

I am confused with a tcsh shell script issue. (for work, no choice in shell, I'm stuck with it)

The enableThingN items below are shell enviroment variables set by other things before running this csh script, using tcsh shell. These are not set within the same script here at all, only evaluated here.

Error message is:

```
enableThing1: Undefined variable.
```

Code is:

```
if ( ( $?enableThing1  &&  ($enableThing1 == 1) ) || \
     ( $?enableThing2  &&  ($enableThing2 == 1) ) || \
     ( $?enableThing3  &&  ($enableThing3 == 1) ) || \
     ( $?enableThing4  &&  ($enableThing4 == 1) )      ) then

    set someScriptVar  = FALSE
else
    set someScriptVar  = TRUE
endif
```

So, as I understand things, the first part of the big if condition is to check if enableThing1 is defined at all or not, using the $?enableThing1 magic. If it is defined, then move on and check the value is 1 or something else. If not defined, then skip the ==1 part of the check for the same shell variable, and move on to see if enableThing2 is defined at all or not, and so on.

As it seems like I am checking for existence, and intend to avoid checking value if it is not defined at all, where have I gone wrong?

I have searched here on stackoverflow and on Google at large, but there are few results and don't get me to an answer, such as:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975968/what-does-var-mean-in-csh
```

Answer (score 0):

An if statement to check the value of the variable requires that the variable exists.

```
if ( ( $?enableThing1  &&  ($enableThing1 == 1) ) || \
#                             ^ this will fail if the variable is not defined.
```

So the if condition turns into

```
if ( ( 0  &&  don'tknowaboutthis ) || \
```

and it falls flat.

Assuming you don't want an if ladder, and functionality to add to this list of variables to check for, you can try the following solution:

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set enableThings = ( enableThing1 enableThing2 enableThing3 enableThing4 ... )

# setting to false initially
set someScriptVar = FALSE

foreach enableThing ($enableThings)

# since we can't use $'s in $? we'll have to do something like this.
  set testEnableThing = `env | grep $enableThing`

# this part is for checking if it exists or not, and if it's enabled or not
  if (($testEnableThing != "") && (`echo $testEnableThing | cut -d= -f2` == 1 )) then
     #  ^ this is to check if the variable is defined       ^ this is to take the part after the =
#                                                             d stands for delimiter
# for example, the output of testEnableThing, if it exists, would be enableThing1=1
# then we take that and cut it to get the value of the variable, in our example it's 1

# if it exists and is enabled, set your someScriptVar
    set someScriptVar = TRUE
# you can put a break here since it's irrelevant to check 
# for other variables after this becomes true
    break
  endif
end
```

This works because we are only working with one variable, "testEnableThing", which is always defined due to the way this works. It can be a blank string, but it will be defined so our if statement won't fall flat.

Hope this solves it for you.

Comment: As came up offline, adding -w to the grep makes it even better, as there was an unexpected shell var name collision without the -w, and grep output multiple lines for multiple vars that confused the if statement and gave an error about if syntax. Thank you!  Sorry that I do not have enough reputation points yet to be allowed to vote up this solution.